# Infinite field K, irreducible, ideals and geometry

Tags: algebraic-geometry, field-theory

Edit : $A_K^n=${$(a_1,...,a_n) |$ all $a_i \in K$, K is a field}

I am doing 1st course on Algebraic Geometry and  I have been following Miles Reid's undergraduate algebraic geometry. I have been trying this exercise and not able to solve it.

> Let $K$ be an arbitrary field. Then show that
>
> - (a) If $K$ is infinite, then $I_K(A_K^n)=0$. In particular, if $K$ is infinite, then $A_K^n$ is irreducible.
> - (b) If $K$ is finite, then find a set of generators for the ideal $I_K (A_K^n)$. Deduce that if $K$ is finite then $A_K^n$ is not irreducible.

My attempt: (a) $I_K(A_K^n)= \{f\in R= K[X_1,...,X_n] \mid f(y)=0 \text{ for all }y \in A_K^n\}$. Let $x\in A_K^n$. Intuition is clear to me how $x$ has to be equal to 0 as for all polynomials $f$, the value at $x$ has to be zero. But, I am not able to prove it rigorously and need hints on which result I should use.

Let $A_K^n =V_1 \cup V_2$ and $V_1 $ and $V_2$ are closed. I have to prove that  either $V_1 = A_K^n$ or $V_2 =A_K^n$. But here also, I am not getting any intuition on which result to use.

(b) I am not able to find the set of generators as again I don't know which result should I use. For proving reducible, I should show that $A_K^n= V_1 \cup V_2$ where both $V_1 $ and $V_2$ are closed and K is finite. But I am not able to construct such $V_1$ and $V_2$.

> Can you please give some hints for these questions?

I shall be really thankful!

Comment: I'm interested in this question but not particularly familiar with notation in algebraic geometry that is apparently fairly standard.  Would you mind defining $A_K^n$ and $I_K(A_K^n)$?

Comment: Right now this is a classic [no-clue question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27923/how-to-prevent-no-clue-questions), and that's not really acceptable for this website. Please take a look at the linked meta page and improve your question via an [edit]. A good place to start would be with a small easy case - try $n=1$, for instance. (The advice in the other comment is also decent - $A^n$ can mean a few different things depending on what level of sophistication you're at, so it's important to define your terms if it's not clear.)

Comment: @KReiser I have added my attempt and thoughts in the question.

Comment: @RobertShore I have mentioned the definition of $I_K (A_K^n)$ in the attempt of (a) and I added the definition $A_K^n$ now by editing it.

Comment: So $A_K^n$ is just the set of all $n$-tuples with all components living in $K$?

Comment: What you've written in your question as your thoughts doesn't really make any sense. "Let $x\in A^n_K$. Intuition is clear to me how $x$ has to be equal to $0$..." doesn't even parse. (You also didn't "add your attempt" - you just changed "attempt" to "my attempt".)  I really would encourage you to try the $n=1$ case first!

Comment: @RobertShore that's one common way to view that, especially in beginning algebraic geometry. Do beware that there's a bit of a viewpoint shift as you progress through the subject - for instance, in many questions asked a little later on in one's journey through algebraic geometry, $\Bbb A^n_k$ will refer to a scheme $\operatorname{Spec} k[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$ which behaves slightly differently but retains the same essential algebro-geometric features as this first definition.

Answer (score 2):

(a) View $f \in K(X_1, \dots, X_{n-1})[X_n]$, then $f$ has infinite many  roots in $K$ as a univariate polynomial in $X_n$.  Deduce that $f$ is a zero polynomial in $K(X_1, \dots, X_{n-1})[X_n]$. Use the criterion that $\Bbb A^n(K)$ is irreducible iff $\mathcal I(\Bbb A^n(K))$ is a prime ideal.

(b) Note that for a finite field $K$ with $q$ elements, every $x \in K$ satisfies $x^q - x = 0$.

#### Update

(a) We induct on $n$. For $n = 1$, $f \in K[X]$ is a univariate polynomial with roots at every element in $K$, therefore the number of roots of $f$ is greater than $\deg f$, which forces $f$ to be $0$ polynomial by undergrad algebra courses. Suppose "For any infinite field $K$, if $f \in K[X_1, \dots, X_{n-1}]$ satisfies $f (\Bbb A_{K}^{n-1}) = 0$ then $f \equiv 0$", then for $f \in K[X_1, \dots, X_n]$ and $f(\Bbb A_K^{n}) = 0$. As Hinted, view $f\in K(X_1, \dots, X_{n-1})[X_n]$, then $\underline{\text{for any }a = (a_1, \dots, a_{n-1})}$, $f(a,X_n)$ is a polynomial in $K[X_n]$ that vanishes on all of $K$. Therefore $f(a, X_n)$ has roots in $K$ more than $\deg_{X_n} f$, which means $\underline{f(a, X_n)\text{ is a }0 \text{ polynomial in }X_n}$. Write in detail:
$$
f(X_1, \dots, X_n) = g_m(X_1, \dots, X_{n-1})X_n^m + g_{m-1}(X_1, \dots, X_{n-1}) X_n^{m-1} + \dots + g_0(X_1, \dots, X_{n-1}), 
$$ where we view all $X_j$ other than $X_n$ as coefficients. Then the underlined part implies that $g_0, \dots, g_{m}$ are polynomials in $X_1, \dots, X_{n-1} $ over $K$ that all vanishes on $\Bbb A_K^{n-1}$. Thus each $g_j$ is $0$ polynomial by the inductive  hypothesis. And the 1st part of (a) is proved.

Comment: Kindly elaborate on how f has infinitely many roots in K and how to deduce that f is a zero polynomial.

Comment: can you please reply to my above question?

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment and edit! I have to prove that ${A_K}^n  $ irreducible but I can't $A_K^n$ is irreducible iif $I(A_n)^K$ is prime as this was not proved in my lectures. I checked my notes again today. Can you please supply a proof of this result and help with (b) also?

Comment: @Avenger Can you please reply if you have some time to spare?